# Microsoft t sql how to declare temporary variable within user defined function?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

So how can I declare a temporary local variable with declare like:`declare @tempVar varchar(max)` within a user declared function?
The actual problem I'm trying to solve here is declaring and using variable within user defined stored function. I declare my function like this:

```
create function someFunction(@someParam varchar(100))
returns table
as 
return (
    declare @tempvar varchar(100)
    set @tempvar = ''--Set the var to something useful
    select * from sometable where somecolumn = (
        select top 1 someColumn
        from sometable
        where somecolumn = @tempvar
    )
)
```

Server complain about the variable being declared in wrong place. Where should I declare my variables in UDF like this?

Comment: You can't. subqueries are optimized as part of the entire query they're a part of. They aren't processed as a separate step, so it wouldn't make sense. If you could explain what data you have and what problem you're trying to solve, we may be able to help.

Comment: declaring a variable inside a UDF is trivial - you write `declare @var type` and you're done. But you originally asked to do it within a *subquery*. That's the bit that needs more explanation of what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps if you provided some sample data and explained what the UDF is meant to compute, we could help you out.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Edited again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating an *Inline Table-valued Function*, this kind of functions must contain only a single `SELECT` statement.

If you want to use variables you must create a *Multi-statement Table-valued Function*. Your function would be declared as:

```
create function someFunction(@someParam varchar(100))
returns @table (field1 type, field2 type, ...)
as 
begin
    declare @tempvar varchar(100)
    set @tempvar = ''--Set the var to something useful
    insert @table
    select * from sometable where somecolumn = (
        select top 1 someColumn
        from sometable
        where somecolumn = @tempvar
    )
    return
end
```

Comment: Oh I see. Never used microsoft databases before, only postgres.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to keep the table function inline you could use a common table expression to define your variable(s) as shown below:

```
create function someFunction(@someParam varchar(100))
returns table
as 
return (
  WITH cte (tempvar) AS
    (
    SELECT '' -- Set the var to something useful
    )
    select * from sometable where somecolumn = (
        select top 1 someColumn
        from sometable
          JOIN cte ON 1=1
        where somecolumn = cte.tempvar
    )
)
```